# How to connect to a remote docker daemon using Docker.dotnet library in C#?

Tags: c#, docker, remote-access

I am new to docker and my current project need to connect to a remote docker daemon. I am developing in dotnet framework and use [docker.dotnet](https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet) library. I have to connect to a remote docker daemon in my network and this is the code I have found:

```
DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(
        new Uri("http://192.168.64.183:2375"))
        .CreateClient();
```

I can connect to local docker daemon by replacing current Uri field with 'http://127.0.0.1:2375' or 'localhost:2375' and its working fine.

But, this is what I'm getting when I try to connect a remote docker daemon,

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Connection failed",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Client.ManagedHandler.<P
.............................something here...............
"InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::ffff:192.168.64.183]:2375",
        "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
        "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Client.ManagedHandler.<TCPSocketOpenerAsync>d__37.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Client.ManagedHandler.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__33.MoveNext()"
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm currently experiencing this issue